# Voom transformation of RNA seq raw counts data

Tags: r, limma

I have RNA seq data of raw gene counts that I want to transform for linear modelling. I am trying to voom transform, to do a weighted analysis.

Data frame: prac_count_10

```
gene         S1     S2    S3   S4    S5 
ENG0000456   0      1     10   145   24
ENG0000458   7      2     9    0     0
ENG0000657   76     12    56   10    2 
ENG0000689   0      0     0    3     5
```

Code:

```
prac_prac_10 <- voom(prac_count_10[,2:5], design=NULL, lib.size=NULL, 
  normalize.method = "none", span = 0.5
```

However this doesn't give an output with the gene sample names and logCPM values. Would like an output with gene id's and logCPM values for linear modelling.

Also tried:

```
cpm <- cpm(prac_count_10)
lcpm <- cpm(prac_count_10, log=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey Holly, you should consider migrating this question to bioinformatics stack exchange, you would get more help on these kind of questions there.. here's the link: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your advice, very kind. I have now posted on there! Thank you